# Rails 3 + Devise - How to get nested resources / routes to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, devise

In my routes.rb file, the only entries I have are:

```
devise_for :users, :path => "accounts"

resources :users do
  resource :profile
end
```

but when I run "rake routes" I can see that there are still mapped resources for the user i.e new, create, edit, update etc...this is causing a conflict with some of the devise paths  such as new_user_registration_path

```
        new_user_session GET    /accounts/sign_in(.:format)            devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /accounts/sign_in(.:format)            devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /accounts/sign_out(.:format)           devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /accounts/password(.:format)           devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /accounts/password/new(.:format)       devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /accounts/password/edit(.:format)      devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /accounts/password(.:format)           devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /accounts/cancel(.:format)             devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /accounts(.:format)                    devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /accounts/sign_up(.:format)            devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /accounts/edit(.:format)               devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /accounts(.:format)                    devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /accounts(.:format)                    devise/registrations#destroy
            user_profile POST   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#create
        new_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)  profiles#new
       edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format) profiles#edit
                         GET    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#show
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                       users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                       users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                   users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)              users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                   users#destroy
```

How can I get rid of the additional user resources which are appearing at the bottom of this output?

Answer (score 0):

If you only wanted, say, index and show, try:

```
devise_for :users, :path => "accounts", :only => [:index, :show] do 
  resource :profile
end
```

Comment: The problem is that I only want the devise created routes for users, right now their is one set of routes, created by devise, and another set created by "resources :users". How can I keep the devise routes & still map profile as a nested resource?

Comment: @Jason I have the same problem with a duplicate set of routes. Have you found a solution to this ?

Comment: Now add some custom omniauth controllers into the mix? I like the idea of having devise concerns seperated from user resources.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to define your Devise (not nested) routes using 'devise_for:', and then in a separate block, do

```
resources :users, :only => :none do
  resource :profile
end
```

Using ':except => :all' stops any non-nested `Users` routes from being defined and overriding your Devise routes, but it still creates all of your `users/3/profile` routes.  Then add `:path => "accounts"` to replace `users`

So your code would look like

```
devise_for :users, :path => "accounts"

resources :users , :path => "accounts", :only => :none do
  resource :profile
end
```